# Meaning of the attribute min_ in MinMaxScaler in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, attributes

From documentation:

> sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.min_ : ndarray, shape (n_features,)
>   Per feature adjustment for minimum.

I don't understand what this means and couldn't find a better explanation elsewhere.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

x_test = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                   [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  1., -1.]])

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(x_test)

print(scaler.min_)
```

which outputs:

```
[0.         0.5        0.33333333]
```

So it's not just the min value observed in the data (which is actually data_min_). What does this min_ attribute represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a good explanation how the `MinMaxScaler` works on the following site: http://benalexkeen.com/feature-scaling-with-scikit-learn/#Min-Max-Scaler

[image]

In scikit-learn you do:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = np.array([[1., -1.,  2.],
              [2.,  0.,  0.],
              [0.,  1., -1.]])

print(x)
# [[ 1. -1.  2.]
#  [ 2.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1. -1.]]

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(x)
x_transformed = scaler.transform(x)

print(x_transformed)
# [[0.5        0.         1.        ]
#  [1.         0.5        0.33333333]
#  [0.         1.         0.        ]]
```

The fitted instance of `MinMaxScaler` saves the means internally:

```py
# [[ 1. -1.  2.]
#  [ 2.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1. -1.]]

print(scaler.data_min_)
#  [ 0. -1. -1.]

print(scaler.data_max_)
#  [ 2.  1.  2.]
```

Alternatively you can compute and scale each value with `numpy`:

```py
x_plain_np = np.apply_along_axis(lambda col: (col- np.min(col)) / (np.max(col) - np.min(col)), 0, x)

print(x_plain_np)
# [[0.5        0.         1.        ]
#  [1.         0.5        0.33333333]
#  [0.         1.         0.        ]]
```

---

Here is all about `self.min_`:

```py
data_range = data_max - data_min
self.scale_ = ((feature_range[1] - feature_range[0]) /
               _handle_zeros_in_scale(data_range))
self.min_ = feature_range[0] - data_min * self.scale_
```

`(0, 1)` is the default value of `feature_range`. In your example we can reproduce each step:

1st: Compute the `data_range`:

```py
data_range = scaler.data_max_ - scaler.data_min_
print(data_range)  # [2. 2. 3.]
```

2nd: Compute the `scale_`:

```py
scale_ = ((scaler.feature_range[1] - scaler.feature_range[0]) / # 1 - 0
          preprocessing.data._handle_zeros_in_scale(data_range))  # we have no zeros
print(scale_)  # [0.5        0.5        0.33333333]
```

Third: Compute the `min_`:

```py
min_ = scaler.feature_range[0] - scaler.data_min_ * scale_
print(min_)  # [0.         0.5        0.33333333]
```

Our result matches the internal result:

```py
print(min_)         # [0.         0.5        0.33333333]
print(scaler.min_)  # [0.         0.5        0.33333333]
```

Finally we can use `scale_` and `min_` to transform our data:

```py
x *= self.scale_
x += self.min_
```

Comment: I have read about this scaler and already knew all that. My question was specifically and **only** about the min_ attribute and this answer doesn't answer that.

Comment: @ChayanGhosh Sure, I added a detailed step by step explanation.